# Can I create a self-signed SSL certificate for Windows Azure using only makecert.exe?

Tags: ssl, azure, makecert

**Background**: I need to test an https endpoint for a WebRole on Windows Azure. For that I need to upload a self-signed certificate, add the certificate's thumbprint to the WebRole's configuration and finally  associate the endpoint with that configured certificate.

I created a self-signed certificate using `makecert.exe`, which is available through the Visual Studio Command Prompt. I used the following command:

```
makecert.exe -r -pe -n "CN=test.cloudapp.net" -sky exchange -ss my -len 2048 test.pfx
```

The command succeeds and I can upload the certificate file to the Windows Azure hosted service. But deployment of the WebRole fails with the following error:

> Certificate with thumbprint 6AB... associated with HTTPS input
>   endpoint Endpoint2 does not contain private key.

I have to export the certificate from the my store, and choose to include the private key and provide a password. If I upload this exported certificate file and use its thumbprint, then deployment succeeds.

I want to create a certificate file that includes the private key, without first saving the certificate to any store and exporting it from the store. Is that possible using `makecert.exe`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To create a certificate without saving it to any store you'll need to use **pvk2pfx.exe** (available through the Visual Studio Command Prompt).

It works like this:

```
makecert.exe -sv CertKey.pvk -n "CN=My Azure Certificate" CertKey.cer
pvk2pfx.exe -pvk CertKey.pvk -spc CertKey.cer -pfx MyPFX.pfx -po yourPasswordHere
```

Running makecert.exe will aks you for a password for the private key. You'll need to enter that password for the -po argument of the pvk2pfx.exe command.

Finally you'll have a pfx file (containing private key) named **MyPFX.pfx**

Comment: I was having some problems getting Azure to accept the PFX file generated by pvk2pfx. A solution was to import the certificate to Windows certificate store and then export from there.

Comment: In case anyone was wondering, once you've done this you can find the certificate's thumbprint on Azure management console.

Comment: @RobChurch or by double clicking on the .cer file.

Comment: Seems you MUST use the -po option with the pvk2pfx to get things to work with Azure. The docs say if there is no -po it uses the one in the .pvk but I could never get Azure to take the .pfx until I explictly used the -po option

Comment: When using a certificate created this way i get the message " SignTool Error: The signer's certificate is not valid for signing." did i do something wrong?